My render (2D animation) does not contain a texture (metallic)
I am a total beginner and I started making my first animation! I finished my animation and wanted to export it. But when I look at the export or render, I get a grey dark model. Not the model with metal.
Do you guys know why?
Thanks for the help

Hello and welcome. Most likely, you didn't add lights and reflection to your scene. Metal needs something to reflect, without that, you will be reflecting the empty world of blender. See https://youtu.be/JM-Z4F3WtmI?si=fCHUXqaLrnP9MMjw&t=119

In your 3D scene you are in Material preview, not Rendered preview, in Material preview you have a default HDRI image that is reflected on the surface of your object, but if you haven't given an HDRI to your World you won't have anything to reflect for render
